# Rails Heroku - Resetting the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, migration, database-migration

I am trying to reset my database.

It isn't working locally or in heroku.

I succuessfully ran each of these commands:

```
1. rake db:drop
2. rake db:create
3. rake db:migrate
```

The migrations took a while to succeed. I commented out the ones that were causing a problem and the whole job finishes migrating.

I then try to reset my database with:

```
4. rake db:reset
```

I get this error:

```
initialize_schema_migrations_table()
   -> 0.0031s
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `name=' for #<University:0x007fc288bdcca0>
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activemodel-4.1.9/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:435:in `method_missing'
```

I can't find anywhere in the code base that has a method called 'name' for university. I have run searches looking for university.name and name near university.

I have updated my gems and run bundle install.

What does this error message mean?

When I try:

```
rake db:reset --trace
```

I get:
    ** Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations
    rake aborted!
    NoMethodError: undefined method `name=' for #<University:0x007f9a1b24da30>
    /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activemodel-4.1.9/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:435:in`method_missing'

I have run all migrations and refreshed rake db:migrate

Comment: Can you please post your schema.rb?

Comment: Any particular bit? its really big

Comment: @user2860931, was your issue solved?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've got something in your `seeds.rb` file causing the error.

The reason you're seeing the issue when running `rake db:reset` but not when running those 3 individual steps is because `rake db:reset` doesn't run those 3 individual steps.

`rake db:reset` will run the following:

```
rake db:drop
rake db:setup
```

and subsequently, `rake db:setup` will run these:

```
rake db:create
rake db:schema:load
rake db:seed
```

If you *only* want to do the initial 3 steps (`rake db:drop`, `rake db:create`, `rake db:migrate`), you can run this instead:

```
rake db:migrate:reset
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the error you get when you are trying to write to a variable that you haven't declared an attr_writer for.

```
class Foo      
  attr_reader :bar

  def initialize
    @bar = 1
  end
end

> f = foo.new
 => #<Foo:0xa22ef0c @bar=1>
> f.bar
 => 1
> f.bar = 2
NoMethodError: undefined method `bar=' for #<Foo:0xa22ef0c @bar=1>
    from (irb):23
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Hi Spiderbites. Not really sure how that relates to my current problem. I am trying to understand why I can successfully drop, create and migrate the db, but I can't reset it because of this method missing error. I don't know what the error message means in my case, or what it means in yours (I don't have any attr_reader/writer declarations in my app - these may be old school rails)

Comment: well db:reset runs the db:setup task which will create the database, load the schema and initialize it with the seed data, so that's doing more than just drop, create & migrate.. http://jacopretorius.net/2014/02/all-rails-db-rake-tasks-and-what-they-do.html

Comment: Thank you - I forgot to check my seed file which had old attributes in it. I deleted that and re ran it. Thanks a lot.